# Sqlite database/file no longer in ios app build

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

This may have been my fault, but I am not sure how to fix the issue. I wanted to change the data installed with my app. Instead of modifying the data in the original sql file in the project, I deleted the sql file from my project and added a new one (with the same name).

Now when I run the app in a simulator it cannot find the sql file. The sql file is also not in the local directory where all my simulator run files are.

I have tried cleaning the build, deleting and cleaning and re-adding, etc.., but my sql file fails to be copied to the simulator directory.

When I deleted the file I removed the reference. Where is this "reference"? I suspect that when I try to re-add the file, it doesn't recreate the reference.

I do not want to have to change the name of the database if that can be avoided.

Edit: Adding a screenshot that shows that file is not included in the target (in this case AmeldaiPhone).

[image]

After checking the checkbox for the target, the file still does not appear in the simulator directory:

Path to simulator directory:
[image]

Contents of simulator directory (where the sql file always showed up before):
[image]

Update: I have revised my project file and the sql file still does not show up in the build. I have determined that this is an issue with the specific target, which was created after the sql file was added. The sql file shows up fine in the build of the original development target.

Comment: You should post how the file was added and show screen shots of it in your project. It is probably just not included in your target. When you click on the file and look at the right hand side of xcode you will see some checkboxes. Make sure the one for your current target is selected or it will not be included. Usually you can just select it and hit delete and then select remove references. Then just re-add it to the project.

Comment: If you want it to be included in AmeldaiPhone or AmeldaiPad builds then you need to make sure you select the target membership checkbox for them.

Comment: The checkbox was not selected for the target (in this case AmeldaiPhone). However, I checked it but still not including the file in the build.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the file? When you check the box it is included in the main bundle of the project.

Comment: See my last pics added. Maybe this is a dumb question, but where is the "main bundle of the project"?

Comment: Trying this again: 1) Delete the file from my project 2) XCode asks if I want to move to trash or remove the reference. I select "remove reference". 3) I select my project, then "Add files to <Projectname>" and grab the file. 4) I click on the file in the project browser and it is not included in my target. I check the box for my target. 5) Clean and build and run: New simulator directory is created but no sql file. Weird.

Comment: I am not sure where the main bundle gets copied to exactly but it is different than the documents directory that you are referencing. I do not know of a way to automatically put a file in the documents directory when an app installs besides coping it from the main bundle to that directory. Maybe check out this resource. https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Comment: I found what I think is the bundle in the Archive directory.. /Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives. No, it doesn't have the sql file in it, but the previous archives do.

Comment: Yea I know the bundle is included in the .ipa file. Looks like that must have been where it was before. It would be a good idea to put this project in source control so you can always revert back to a good working project if you make a mistake.

Comment: Fortunately I just recently put it in source control, and I'm trying understand the git diff output to figure out which file changed (other than those I know about).

Comment: I determined that the file changed was project.pbxproj, went back to a previous version, and still no luck. I also tried duplicating the file and adding that. The weird thing is that it shows up fine in my development target, so I think it must have something to do with the target. I'm going to add this to my question.

Comment: Figured out a weird fix, see my answer. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this is happening, but I was able to fix my own problem by *unchecking* the development target for my sql file, and cleaning and building. The file then appears in my deployment target..

Unchecked development target, checked deployment target..
[image]

Path to simulator directory:
[image]

File appears in simulator directory.
[image]

That seemed to unstick whatever weird thing was stuck. The file is now included in all target builds.